# Proper use of namespaces for function definitions in cpp file

Tags: c++, namespaces, function-pointers

So for some reason I have experienced the behavior that adding a namespace to my .h and .cpp files for a set of functions breaks my linker. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Here's my scenario (simplified)

functions.h

```
int functionA();
int functionB();
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"

int functionA() { return 0; }//we could pretend there's actual code here
int functionB() { return 0; }//we could pretend there's actual code here
```

and the actual useage of it is in some cpp file thusly:

pointers.h

```
#include "functions.h"

class GetPointers
{
public:
    typedef int (*FunctionPointer)(void);

    static FunctionPointer funcPointerA() { return &functionA; }
    static FunctionPointer funcPointerB() { return &functionB; }
};
```

Well that's all fine and dandy. I can call the static method of GetPointers and get a function pointer which works. Everythings been tested and everything is happy. Now I thought I would simply add some namespaces to make sure I don't have any problems again in the future. So I simply modify the three code files to use namespaces. What happens is a link error which refers to the function funcPointerA() and funcPointerB() of the GetPointers class, with the full namespace name to functionA and functionB.

functions.h

```
namespace fun {

int functionA();
int functionB();

}
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"

using namespace fun;

int functionA() { return 0; }//we could pretend there's actual code here
int functionB() { return 0; }//we could pretend there's actual code here
```

and the actual useage of it is in some cpp file thusly:

pointers.h

```
#include "functions.h"

namespace fun {

class GetPointers
{
public:
    typedef int (*FunctionPointer)(void);

    static FunctionPointer funcPointerA() { return &functionA; }
    static FunctionPointer funcPointerB() { return &functionB; }
};

}
```

I don't get a build error, only a link error about fun::functionA and fun::functionB. **Is there something implicitly wrong with using function pointers from namespaces?**

Comment: `using namespace fun;` only lets you use functions from the `fun` namespace. It does not make `functionA` and `functionB` part of that namepsace. You have in effect redeclared those functions in the global scope for that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your definitions:

```
int functionA() { return 0; }
int functionB() { return 0; }
```

are in the global namespace; so they declare new functions there rather than define the functions declared in `namespace fun`.

The best fix is to qualify the names in the definitions:

```
int fun::functionA() { return 0; }
int fun::functionB() { return 0; }
```

This is preferable to putting the definitions inside the namespace, since it gives a compile-time check that the functions match their declarations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick an concise answer.